# Primary key in xsd not working

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have following XML

```
    <SourceDataSet xmlns="C:/Users/AGARWALN/Desktop/NidhiTest/SourceDataSet.xsd">
    <SourceSystem>
    <SystemCode>XTRADER</SystemCode>
    </SourceSystem>
```

and xsd as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:mstns="C:/Users/AGARWALN/Desktop/NidhiTest/SourceDataSet.xsd"        xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"

xmlns="C:/Users/AGARWALN/Desktop/NidhiTest/SourceDataSet.xsd" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="C:/Users/AGARWALN/Desktop/NidhiTest/SourceDataSet.xsd" id="SourceDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" name="SourceDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="SourceSystem">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="SystemCode">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:maxLength value="20" />
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

 <xs:key name="PK_SourceSystem">
  <xs:selector xpath="SourceDataSet/SourceSystem"/>    
     <xs:field xpath="SystemCode"/></xs:key>
</xs:element>

   </xs:schema>
```

All the validation are working except my primary key validation. Its is all working with default namespace given in http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp

Thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 0):

is it the real representation of your xml and xsd files?
Have you closed the xml "SourceDataSet" tag and the "xs:sequence", "xs:complexType", "xs:element" xsd tags?

Comment: No actually, my xml is much complex.. i have just given a part. of it .. the xml and xsd are well formed...When i am using default namespaces like                                         <SourceDataSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  in xml and <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"> in my xsd. the code is working.. But as i have used mine namespace it is detecting all other validation but not primary key